# JavaScript regex to match the very precise number of the same characters

Tags: javascript, regex

String example:

```
~~333~~
```

I need to get everything inbetween

```
~~
```

Regex that works:

```
/^(~{2})(.*?)(~{2})$/gm
```

But it also gets this string:

```
~~~333~~~
```

and also this:

```
~~~~333~~~~
```

What regex will get only the first one?

Comment: I need to get everything in between ~~, which one ? You have two (the outer one or the inner one) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a lookaround approach on both ends to ensure that tilde does not precede or follow the `~~` markers.

```js
var input = "~~333~~ ~~~444~~~ ~~~~5555~~~~";
var matches = input.match(/(?:^|[^~])~~([^~]+)~~(?!~)/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason your regex is matching the latter two test cases is because of your wildcard character `.` is picking up the inner `~`s. To fix this, and make it only match numbers you could do this:

```
/^~{2}([0-9]*)~{2}$/gm
```

If you want to catch other characters as well as long as they ae not `~` you could match all characters excluding the `~` character like this:

```
^~{2}([^~]*)~{2}$
```

Both of these only match the first test case `~~333~~` and not the others.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^~~[^~\r\n]+~~$
```

`^` match the start of the line.

`~~` match two literal `~`.

`[^~\r\n]+` match one or more character that is not `~` because we don't want to cross the two closing `~~`, and also not `\r` or `\n` because we also don't want to cross newline characters.

`~~` match two literal `~`.

`$` match the end of the line.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJEhFV/1).

Answer (score 0):

The below regex will match for exact two '~' in beginning and at last. And any string between those.

```
/^(~{2})([^~]*)(~{2})$
```

Answer (score 0):

As you used anchors in your current pattern with `(.*?)` to match *anything* in between, and you are using JavaScript in an environment that [supports a lookbehind assertion](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind), you can use a single capture group to get the desired value:

```
^~~(?!~)(.*)~(?<!~.)~$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `~~` Match literally
- `(?!~)` Negative lookahead, assert not a ~ directly to the right of the current position
- `(.*)` Capture **group 1**, match any character 0 or more times
- `~(?<!~.)` Match the first ~ and assert that there is not a ~ directly to the left of the current position
- `~` Match the second ~
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/PdOHc2/1).

```js
const regex = /^~~(?!~)(.*)~(?<!~.)~$/;
[
  "~~333~~",
  "~~this is ~~~~~ a test ~~ test~~",
  "~~~333~~~",
  "~~~~333~~~~",
  "~~~this is ~ a test ~~ test~~test~~"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) console.log(m[1]);
});
```

**Some other variations**

If you want to capture 1 or more digits in between:

```
^~~(\d+)~~$
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/GxEDjD/1)

If you want to capture multiple occurrences without overlap:

```
(?<!~)~~(?!~)(.*?)~(?<!~.)~(?!~)
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/A051jL/1)

If you want to capture multiple occurrences with overlap:

```
(?<!~)~~(?!~)(.*?)(?=~(?<!~.)~(?!~))
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ksNgxP/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. this is to remove all special characters and return text and number value only :)

```
/[^a-zA-Z ]/g

var str = "~~333~~";
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
```